# How does emacs flash its icon on the windows taskbar?

Tags: microsoft-windows, error-handling, notifications

Sometimes when I run a process if there is an error during the process the emacs icon on the windows taskbar lights up, so if I'm in an other app I can see something happened there.

I'd like to use this indication in my elisp programs too. Is there a lisp call which makes the emacs icon light up on the taskbar?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this helps? `(let ((visible-bell  t)) (ding t))`

Comment: @Drew I tried it like this `(progn (sleep-for 3) (let ((visible-bell t)) (ding t)))` and it did highlight the emacs icon when I was in an other app. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using function `ding` with variable `visible-bell` bound to non-`nil`. For example:

```lisp
(let ((visible-bell t)) (ding t))
```

If you need to impose a delay before flashing then you can use `sit-for` or `sleep-for`. For example:

```lisp
(let ((visible-bell t))
  (sleep-for 2) ; Wait 2 seconds
  (ding t)) ; Flash screen
```